# Upgrading Typescript version: Inheritance issues: Property <x> in type <y> is not assignable to the same property in the base type

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a large application which has a model based on a number of abstract base classes. This all worked on our previous Typescript version (2.3), however that's very old and I want to upgrade to v3.5.

Code that has compiled for some time is now throwing errors. I've reduced this to a minimal reproduction from my scenario, however there are a number of locations that are causing the same issues.

I'm not clear on the best/easiest/least impact way of resolving this without rearchitecting the whole model.

```
class B{
    prop:string;

     doStuff<T extends B>(p:T) : void{
        this.prop = p.prop;
    }
}

class C extends B {
    prep : string;

    doStuff(p : C):void{
        this.prep = p.prep
        super.doStuff(p);
    }
}
```

Errors are as follows:

```
tstest.ts(16,5): error TS2416: Property 'doStuff' in type 'C' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'B'.
  Type '(p: C) => void' is not assignable to type '<T extends B>(p: T) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'p' and 'p' are incompatible.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'C'.
        Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'C'.
          Property 'prep' is missing in type 'B'.
tstest.ts(18,23): error TS2345: Argument of type 'C' is not assignable to parameter of type 'B'.
  Types of property 'doStuff' are incompatible.
    Type '(p: C) => void' is not assignable to type '<T extends B>(p: T) => void'.
```

Comment: This feels bigger than a [mcve], but I think you will probably want to use [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) instead of trying to narrow method parameters in subclasses.  So `copyFrom<TModel extends this>`.  But there's a lot going on here that wants to be addressed also (e.g., maybe turn on `--strictNullChecks` and deal with those issues, maybe make `copyFrom` a concrete method and not a generic one since `f<T extends A>(t: T){}` is similar to the simpler `f(t: A){}`, etc) so I'm not sure where to go here

Comment: Are you able to elaborate at all on why the last error is thrown? Type Foo extends type BaseAuditedModel, so why is the Type constraint not met?

Comment: If you'd like to distill this down into a [mcve] where the only issues with the code are the issues you're having problems with, and without any code unrelated to the problem, I'd be happy to take a closer look at it.

Comment: ok, I've pared it back, but also have been doing further reading and think I need to get a better understanding of Typescript inheritance and type assertion. i.e. I would have expected (from other languages) that in the above, C would have just had to be a superset of B, however it appears that assignment needs to be able to take place in each direction... back to the drawing board.